# run android app into blackberry get '<AppName> has stopped', build app with Delphi XE7

Tags: android, delphi, blackberry, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I'v build a simple blank Firemonkey application in XE7.
This app runs on an Nexus7 (Android). 
Now I want to run this app on a BlackBerry OS10.
I have a BlackBerry Simulator on my pc.
I can run the .apk on the simulator. After the installation I can run the app.
Afther the default splashscreen of the firemonkeylogo, I get a message 'App has stopped'. Then the app stop.

I get also this error on a BlackBerry Z10.

Can someone help me to look in the right direction?

Solved:

With the last updates of Blackberry I can run the apk on a blackberry device.

Comment: Running Android apps on BBOS10 is very sensitive to the particular Android runtime that you have installed on the BB device

Comment: So I must check on the BlackBerry Simulator which Android runtime it used?

Comment: That's where I'd start. It's a bit of a black art getting Android software to run on BBOS10.